# jquery show hide element according to boolean value boolean

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use those rows to show hide some elements:

```
function isActive()
{
     $("#id1").hide();
     $("#id2").show();
}
```

But I need to change the rows above to make elements dispayed or hide according to bool value:

```
function isActive(toShow)
{
     $("#id1").hide();
     $("#id2").show();
}
```

what is the best way to implemnt it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`$.fn.toggle(Boolean: display)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display):

```
function isActive(toShow)
{
     $("#id1").toggle(!toShow);  // Hide when toShow = true, show when toShow = false
     $("#id2").toggle(!!toShow); // Hide when toShow = false, show when toShow = true
}
```

It is however important to make sure `toShow` is a boolean.

Comment: You can even just instead use `$("#id1, #id2").toggle()`, doesn't make a difference.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Well that depends on the initial state of `#id1` and `#id2`

Comment: Perfect. Agreed. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

That's perfectly the better way, but the best way would be setting an event handler and use of classes:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".cont").hide();
  $(".trig").click(function () {
    $(".cont").hide();
    $($(this).attr("href")).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<a class="trig" href="#id-1">Display 1</a>
<a class="trig" href="#id-2">Display 2</a>
<a class="trig" href="#id-3">Display 3</a>
<div id="id-1" class="cont">Contents of Item 1</div>
<div id="id-2" class="cont">Contents of Item 2</div>
<div id="id-3" class="cont">Contents of Item 3</div>
```

If you have set the two elements correctly (one hidden, one visible), you can just use the following code to toggle their visibility:

```
$("#id1, #id2").toggle();
```

A demo of it would be:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<a href="#" onclick='$("#id1, #id2").toggle(); return false;'>Toggle Display</a>
<div id="id1" style="display: none;">Contents of Item 1</div>
<div id="id2">Contents of Item 2</div>
```

> **Note:** The above works only for the two, and it is very much hard coded.